# What is "playground mode" in Google's Colaboratory?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I recently discovered Colaboratory. After playing with it for a few minutes, I have some idea what "playground mode" is - that no output is saved in that mode, but couldn't find a formal note in the FAQ or other help material (intro notebook) that I located. I'm wondering if there are more details to know about this mode and when is it suggested to be used?

Thanks.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Playground mode opens an ephemeral copy of the notebook that isn't saved.

Typical uses include:

- Tweaking an existing notebook without cluttering the original.
- Executing or editing a notebook shared with read-only permissions

Without playground mode, these tasks would require creating a copy of the notebook in Drive, which clutters the file list a bit. (Of couse, you can always save a copy of the notebook after opening in playground mode if needed.)